# error while trying to remove element by index from list

Tags: java, list

Q: Reverse a list (make your own method, don't use collections)

I'm getting an error `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        T t;
        t = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0); //error
        reverse(list);
        list.add(t);
    }
}
```

Test

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40);
reverse(integerList);
```

I don't understand why I'm getting `UnsupportedOperationException` on `list.remove(0);`

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40)` returns a fixed sized list backed by an array. You cannot add or remove elements from it.

Try to pass the following `List` instead:

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40));
```